# Nested List Toggle not working Material UI REACT

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm fairly new to the react and as the title states, I've set-up a nested list using material-ui [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list). But so far I'm trying to figure out why the nested list won't toggle code is below. I've also tried removing my customization and used the source from the documentation and the issue still persists. I think I'm missing a dependency or something, please help.

> ```
>    export default class User_list extends React.Component{
>    render(){
>     return(
>         <div className={"tm-sidebarleft uk-width-3-10"}>
>         <List>
>             <ListItem primaryText="Dashboard" leftIcon={<ActionAssessment />} />
>                 <ListItem
>                     primaryText="View Users"
>                     leftIcon={<CommunicationContacts />}
>                     initiallyOpen={true}
>                     primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
>                     nestedItems={[
>                          <ListItem
>                             key={1}
>                             primaryText="Edit Users"
>                             leftIcon={<ActionAccountbox style={iconStyles} color={yellow600} />}
>                           />
>                     ]}
>              />
>         </List>
>         </div>
>     );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui#react-tap-event-plugin